# Java cannot write to database due to "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to use a Java [application](https://github.com/goeh/weather-collector) to get data from a weather station and write them into a database but I keep receiving the exception

```sh
Sep 21, 2021 5:15:35 PM se.technipelago.weather.archive.SqlDataStore init
SEVERE: Cannot connect to database
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'weather'@'localhost'
```

thrown by [this function](https://github.com/goeh/weather-collector/blob/a3d8af143de92830ccd4bffac053c40b36c94cc5/src/main/java/se/technipelago/weather/archive/SqlDataStore.java#L76).

This is how my `collector.properties` files looks like:

```
datastore.type=jdbc
datastore.name=weather
datastore.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
datastore.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/weather?user=weather&password=weather
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Please check user access level in database for weather

Comment: this is probably something dumb I am doing but.. I do not have a database. I thought the application is creating one for me!

Comment: Correct; if the database does not exist, you get an access denied error. It's an error meant to be obscure deliberately, because if it told you the database does not exist, then a hacker could use that to find out which databases you do have.

Comment: Thanks guys! The issue was solved by creating a database indeed! If you answer below I will accept the answer, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by actually creating the database as it was not existing.